# How can I import serenity test results to XRay test execution?

Tags: cucumber-serenity, jira-xray

Test results of serenity/cucumber can't be uploaded to Jira/Xray Test Execution task.

Tests executed with mvn clean verify.
Upload of Json file results in "No tests found in execution result".
Upload of XML file results in "description -> Description is required.". Even if I add a description to testsuite and testcase, the same error occurs.

How can I import the test results?

**Xray version:** 3.4.2_j7

**Dependencies:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.37</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.55</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.55</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.55</version>
            <configuration>
              <tags></tags>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**XML result file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="simple text search" skipped="0" tests="10" time="77.58" timestamp="2019-07-30 02:16:13">
   <testcase name="find a document by using the simple text search"/>
</testsuite>
```

**JSON result file:**

```
{
  "name": "find a document by using the simple text search",
  "id": "simple-text-search;find-a-document-by-using-the-simple-text-search",
  "testSteps": [
    {
      "number": 1,
      "description": "Example #1: {searchTerm\u003dquality assurance, documentTitle\u003dBRPM.LO Assurance Mgmt.}",
      "duration": 7118,
      "startTime": "2019-07-30T14:16:13.374+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
      "result": "SUCCESS",
      "precondition": false,
      "level": 0,
      "children": [
        {
          "number": 2,
          "description": "Login: user, password",
          "duration": 5897,
          "startTime": "2019-07-30T14:16:13.395+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
          "result": "SUCCESS",
          "precondition": false,
          "level": 1
        },
        {
          "number": 3,
          "description": "Is dashboard opened",
          "duration": 135,
          "startTime": "2019-07-30T14:16:19.293+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
          "result": "SUCCESS",
          "precondition": false,
          "level": 1
        },
        {
          "number": 4,
          "description": "Given the user opens the search",
          "duration": 208,
          "startTime": "2019-07-30T14:16:19.428+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
          "result": "SUCCESS",
          "precondition": false,
          "level": 1,
          "children": [
            {
              "number": 5,
              "description": "Open search",
              "duration": 201,
              "startTime": "2019-07-30T14:16:19.434+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
              "result": "SUCCESS",
              "precondition": false,
              "level": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "number": 6,
          "description": "When documents are filtered with simple text search \"quality assurance\"",
          "duration": 395,
          "startTime": "2019-07-30T14:16:19.636+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
          "result": "SUCCESS",
          "precondition": false,
          "level": 1,
          "children": [
            {
              "number": 7,
              "description": "Filter documents by text: quality assurance",
              "duration": 393,
              "startTime": "2019-07-30T14:16:19.637+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
              "result": "SUCCESS",
              "precondition": false,
              "level": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "number": 8,
          "description": "Then the document with title \"BRPM.LO Assurance Mgmt.\" must be found on first place",
          "duration": 357,
          "startTime": "2019-07-30T14:16:20.032+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
          "result": "SUCCESS",
          "precondition": false,
          "level": 1,
          "children": [
            {
              "number": 9,
              "description": "Is document on first place: BRPM.LO Assurance Mgmt.",
              "duration": 356,
              "startTime": "2019-07-30T14:16:20.033+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
              "result": "SUCCESS",
              "precondition": false,
              "level": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "number": 10,
          "description": "Logout",
          "duration": 101,
          "startTime": "2019-07-30T14:16:20.390+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
          "result": "SUCCESS",
          "precondition": false,
          "level": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "userStory": {
    "id": "simple-text-search",
    "storyName": "simple text search",
    "path": "src/test/resources/features/search/SimpleTextSearch.feature",
    "narrative": "\tWithin the Search you can use a simple full text search to find documents.",
    "type": "feature"
  },
  "featureTag": {
    "name": "search/simple text search",
    "type": "feature",
    "displayName": "search/simple text search"
  },
  "title": "find a document by using the simple text search",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "search",
      "type": "capability",
      "displayName": "Search"
    },
    {
      "name": "TPD-3150",
      "type": "tag",
      "displayName": "TPD-3150"
    },
    {
      "name": "search/simple text search",
      "type": "feature",
      "displayName": "simple text search"
    }
  ],
  "startTime": "2019-07-30T14:16:13.371+02:00[Europe/Berlin]",
  "duration": 77582,
  "projectKey": "",
  "sessionId": "8e2f1927ce30efaa140c889e54081a9b",
  "driver": "chrome",
  "dataTable": {
    "headers": [
      "searchTerm",
      "documentTitle"
    ],
    "rows": [
      {
        "values": [
          "quality assurance",
          "BRPM.LO Assurance Mgmt."
        ],
        "result": "SUCCESS"
      }
    ],
    "predefinedRows": true,
    "scenarioOutline": "Given the user opens the search\n\rWhen documents are filtered with simple text search \"\u003csearchTerm\u003e\"\n\rThen the document with title \"\u003cdocumentTitle\u003e\" must be found on first place\n\r",
    "dataSetDescriptors": [
      {
        "startRow": 0,
        "rowCount": 0,
        "name": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  "manual": false,
  "testSource": "Cucumber",
  "result": "SUCCESS",
  "scenarioOutline": "Given the user opens the search\r\nWhen documents are filtered with simple text search \"\u003csearchTerm\u003e\"\r\nThen the document with title \"\u003cdocumentTitle\u003e\" must be found on first place"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have recently written this Serenity BDD tutorial which describes two possible flows in case you aim to have full visibily of Gherkin.

https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/XRAY/Testing+using+Serenity+BDD+and+Cucumber+in+Java

If you aim to report against existing Gherkin tests in Xray (i.e. "Cucumber Tests"), you need to export first the tests out of Jira so they can be tagged with the corresponding issue keys.
If you just submit the cucumber JSON report, Xray cannot do the autoprovisioning of the corresponding Scenearios/Tests.

If you do use JUnit XML reports as means to submit back the results, then Xray will do autoprovisioning of "generic" (i.e. unstructured) test cases, that don't contain the gherkin sentences. Even though this alternate flow is simpler just to have visibility of automation results, it won't provide gherkin sentences details nor ensures that the autoprovisioned tests will be reused correctly afterwards (it depends on how Serenity BDD maps the results to the  elements on the JUnit XML report).

In sum, to have full visibility choose one of the supported flows (either Xray or git as master), and  then the corresponding steps which will require you to export the features of Jira so they get properly tagged.